# Trouble using Parity execute whitehat etc refund contract

Tags: parity

I am trying to use the whitehat refund contract on the ETC chain.  The contract address is here:  0x9f5304da62a5408416ea58a17a92611019bd5ce3

and have mostly been following this tutorial.

The problem is that when I add the contract with abi to parity I don't actually see the withdraw option as one of the queries.

[image]

I can go to execute, but then I don't understand what options to choose